# error to write text to a text file line by line by appending in C# , but got nothing in the file

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, streamwriter, console.writeline

I am working on C# on Win7 VS 2012.

I need to write text to a text file line by line by appending.

```
 StreamWriter ofile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\myPath\my_data_output.txt", true);

  ofile.WriteLine(myString + "\t");
```

But, there is nothing in the output file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your code in a using clause.
This will call the Dispose method on the `StreamWriter` class.
The `Dispose` method calls the `Flush` method, which writes to the stream.

Your code would look like this:

```
using (StreamWriter ofile = 
           new StreamWriter(@"C:\myPath\my_data_output.txt", true)
{
    ofile.WriteLine(myString + "\t"); 
}
```

You can always call the flush method at any time.

Answer (score 0):

or better ofile.Close(); which closes the stream and also flushs it when you finished with it
[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I need to write many lines by loop. If I do close() every iteration, are there performance ovehead ? Thanks –

Comment: just write all the  lines and after the loop close it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use System.IO.File static class it takes care of flushing and disposing, you just need to call AppendAllText method like this:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\myPath\my_data_output.txt", myString + "\t");
```

And if you need to call it many times then my suggestion is using StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(condition)
{
    //Your loop body

    sb.AppendText(myString + "\t");
}
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\myPath\my_data_output.txt",sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(SOME CONDITION)
{
    sb.AppendLine("YOUR STRING"); 

}
// Set boolean to true to append to the existing file.
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\AllTxtFiles.txt", true))
{
    outfile.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}



//Append new text to an existing file. 
// The using statement automatically closes the stream and calls  
// IDisposable.Dispose on the stream object. 
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", true))
{
    file.WriteLine("Your line");
}
```

Also, make sure that you have write permission on the dir/file you are trying to write to and that you are running your application as an admin.